# Codeigniter ERROR: Module 'dba' already loaded

Tags: php, codeigniter

A PHP Error was encountered

> ```
> Severity: Core Warning
> Message: Module 'dba' already loaded
> Filename: Unknown
> Line Number: 0
> ```

Backtrace:

Hi ,

Suddenly got this error for Codeigniter 3.0.1.

I have no idea about this kind of error and never got this error before.

Any suggestion would be a great help .

Comment: Are you using Apache, nginx or FPM?

Comment: I am using apache

Comment: Go to command prompt and check output of php -i | grep php.ini

If you get the same error there, it means you are loading dba module twice in php.ini.

Comment: Right at this moment i am using a shared hosting server. so don't have the access to use command

Answer (score 0):

Check your php.ini file & comment out that specific extension/module. Hope it will not show this error any more.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

After doing some research i have found an interesting solution. I have just unchecked the option dba from cpanel > choose php version and my problem is solved